# Need to take bootable usb image of installed system

Tags: system-installation, backup

I installed Ubuntu 12.04, Java, PostgreSQL and some other applications on a desktop. I need the same things installed on other machines with the same hardware configuration but I don't want to ghost the entire system I want a LiveUSB installer.

Are there any applications available for converting a live system configuration into an Live installer?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Remastersys](http://remastersys.com).

Although its development is no longer taking place, you can still download it from [here](http://www.remastersys.com/downloads/) and install the deb file using `dpkg`.

`sudo dpkg -i <filename>.deb`

It can be used to create custom bootable ISOs (LiveCD) which can be customised according to the user's preference in terms of the packages installed, themes, etc.

For a tutorial, you can visit [this](http://linuxhalwa.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-create-ubuntu-live-cddvd-using.html) page.

Comment: Hi I need installed application on ubuntu but no home folder and no user name if i boot iso means it have to ask new user name password like wise new install but it must contains all existing application please give me a procedure to do this

Comment: In remastersys, select the `Dist` option if you want to create a livecd with your existing applications.